# Using a press enter to continue random num guesser - skips input on first try

Tags: c++

On first run it skips the press enter input. After this it works fine
It should do the following :

- Ask you to pick a number (working)
- Guess number (working)
- Ask you to press enter to continue (not working skips over first input for enter works fine 2nd try).

My code:

```
while (counter != guess)
{
    int randnum = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
    counter = randnum;
    counter2++;

    if (counter == guess)
    {
        cout << "The computer has guessed your number to be " << guess << 
                ". The computer got this answer in " << counter2 << " tries." << 
                endl;

    }
    else if (counter > guess)
    {
        cout << "The computer has guessed your number to be " << counter << 
                ". This answer is greater than your input. " << endl;
        max = counter - 1;
    }
    else if (counter < guess)
    {
        cout << "The computer has guessed your number to be " << counter << 
                ". This answer is less than your input. " << endl;
        min = counter + 1;
    }

    cout << "Press Enter to Continue" << endl;
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
}
```

Comment: Always trim example code down to a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do `std::cin` you are taking any characters up to the next white space. When you input a number that the computer is trying to guess, you are actually putting in `50\n` instead of `50`. This means the `cin` takes the 50, but leaves the `\n`, which is picked up by the `cin.ignore()`. When the program gets to the `cin.ignore()`, because there is something in the stream, that is dealt with first, then input is gotten from the user. Since `\n` is already in the stream, that is dealt with first and satisfies that line of code, so it moves on.